# Low Resolution and Nvidia GPU and drivers not detecting

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, display-resolution, gpu-driver

I am a new user. I installed by dual booting ubuntu 16.04 just to use ROS. But after installing the resolution is 1024 x 768 but my monitor resolution 1920 x 1080. And when I see the details from settings it says my gpu is llvmpipe. But my gpu is 1660 super. Also, there is no additional drivers to be installed in software and updates. I tried installing after downloading the nvidia driver from their website and tried to run it after making it executable but it says cannot open NVIDIA x86 x64.......run.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 will be out of support in 5 days and questions about will no longer be accepted. Also it's way too old for such GPU.

Comment: Just a reminder 16.04 reaches end of standard support between  April 22  and 30 2021. You may want to think about upgrading to 18.04 or 20.04. End of Stand Support means no more support or updates. You may not ask questions here either as 16.04 will be off topic. If you sign up for ESM you can still get security patches but that is all. You can sign up for ESM starting on April 30.